# Assign account throws CrmException: "All entities must be found."

Tags: dynamic, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I am getting an error like All entities must be found while assigning the owner. whle googling I have found the solution from link http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6878b165-9d8d-405e-b076-b16e67c71095/assign-account-throws-crmexception-all-entities-must-be-found?forum=crmdeployment

This works fine to me but this should not be the solution. i need to do this process whenever this type of error occurs.

does any body know the solution.

do you have any idea why this type of error occurs.

Comment: I'm sorry Kartik but this question doesn't belong to stackoverflow, I vote to close, hope you understand.

Comment: can i ask you the reason for it?

Comment: This is the MS CRM question and not sure whats wrong in this.

Comment: this question is not about programming, my suggestion is to post on microsoft forums

Comment: but this is the technical question.

Comment: Kartik, you can read the help center here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and decide by yourself if this question belongs to stackoverflow. I voted to close the question because in my opinion it doesn't and it's better to post on microsoft forums.